# Static variables not being inherited in child classes

Tags: php, oop, static, isset, defined

For some reason I cannot get static variables to be inherited in child classes. The following snippet seems ok, but does not work.

```
abstract class UserAbstract {
    // Class variables
    protected $type;
    protected $opts;
    protected static $isLoaded = false;
    protected static $uid = NULL;

    abstract protected function load();
    abstract protected function isLoaded();
}


class TrexUserActor extends TrexUserAbstract {
    // protected static $uid;  // All is well if I redefine here, but I want inheritance
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load();  
    }

    protected function load() {
        if (!$this->isLoaded()) {
            // The following does NOT work. I expected self::$uid to be available...
            if (defined(static::$uid)) echo "$uid is defined";
            else echo self::$uid . " is not defined";  

            echo self::$uid;
            exit;

            // Get uid of newly created user
            self::$uid = get_last_inserted_uid();

            drupal_set_message("Created new actor", "notice");
            // Flag actor as loaded
            self::$isLoaded = true;

            variable_set("trex_actor_loaded", self::$uid);
        } else {
            $actor_uid = variable_set("trex_actor_uid", self::$uid);
            kpr($actor_uid);
            exit;
            $actor = user_load($actor_uid);
            drupal_set_message("Using configured trex actor ($actor->name)", "notice");  
        }
    }
}
```

Aside from the possible copy-paste/reformat errors, the above code does not have the parent`s static variables, so I guess I am missing a detail somewhere.

Any clue on what is happening is appreciated.

Comment: [Works for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27c3e6f4075ac9e9c306bdfe9203df4d7b327884). Did you forget to derive `TrexUserAbstract` from `UserAbstract`?

Comment: Ah man. This is weird, as I have identical code as your fiddle except I am using an autoloade.  I have version 5.3.2-1,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`defined`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) only applies to constants. You should be using [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1):

I see several errors. You meant?

```
if (isset(self::$uid))
    echo "\$uid: " . self::$uid . " is defined";
else
    echo "\$uid is not defined";
```

**UPDATE**:

To be clear, as @stefgosselin and @supericy says the bug was caused by use `defined` instead `isset`. In php5.3+ was added [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

**So in php5.3+ this will work:**

```
if (isset(static::$uid))
    echo "\$uid: " . static::$uid . " is defined";
else
    echo "\$uid is not defined";
```

And from out of `TrexUserActor` class this will work too:

```
if (isset(TrexUserActor::$uid))
    echo "\$uid: " . TrexUserActor::$uid . " is defined";
else
    echo "\$uid is not defined";
```

Comment: Yes. The isset was the problem thanks friend. This if was just  to have a quick debug output, just meant to indicate success or failure in the heat of the moment. Thanks again.